# WebStorm: how to save mocha path in the shared configuration files

Tags: mocha.js, webstorm

I have the following problem:

I created configurations to run mocha tests that I want to share within my team. They are stored in `*.xml` files in `runConfigurations` folder.

I submit everything except w`orkspace.xml` file to the git repo. But when I checkout this project on the clean machine, then the field for mocha path is missing:

[image: this is what I have on the clean machine]

I use mocha from my `node_modules`.

What should I do ?

Also, when I set `NODE_PATH` for Node.js in `Run -> Edit Configurations ... -> Defaults -> Node.js`, then this parameter is not saved as well.

Comment: *"Also, when I set NODE_PATH for Node.js in Run -> Edit Configurations ... -> Defaults -> Node.js" For this moment `-> Defaults ->` is the key here -- entries under Defaults branch affect only future new Configurations created on that machine -- they are not part of any existing Configuration and do not affect any existing Configurations as well. AFAIK Defaults are stored in `workspace.xml` **P.S.** No idea on first/subject issue

Answer (score 0):

`Mocha package` value is not saved in run configuration `.xml`, this option is common for all Mocha configurations and thus is stored in `workspace.xml` as

```
<component name="NodeJsMochaPackageDirSetting">
    <data>path\to\node_modules\mocha</data>
</component>
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to submit my configs to the .git repo for other developers, so they dont need to specify this path our self. According to the documentation, this file is user specific, so it should not be shared.

Comment: Committing the workspace.xml would be a disaster, since it also contains open windows and other stuff, which is probably gonna change with each commit, where the commit author has used Webstorm. So dirty merge conflicts would be a regular thing. Unfortunately I haven't found any information, if there's another place, where you can override environment variables of run configurations.